# Equivalent of `-s` when calling pytest with pytest.main()

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I am calling in my script, `pytest.main()`; although I get no print out unless the test fail.

I know that pytest has a `-s` flag that solve the problem, and in fact if I call my test from console using

`python3 -m pytest -s mytest.py`

Works just fine and I get the print statements printed correctly even if the test pass; but I can't find how do you obtain the same outcome while calling pytest.main() from a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Anything you pass from command line can be put in the `args` list:

```
pytest.main(args=['-s', 'mytest.py'])
```

From the [`pytest.main` docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-main):

> Parameters:
>
> - **args** – list of command line arguments.

Comment: Glad I could help!